# A long, almost for physics riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

I came up with this riddle today:

> My Whole is of 2 terms.
> My Prefix is 3 Letters.
>
> Term 1 is half open.
> But Term 2 is mostly locked.
>
> My Prefix is an ex.
> My Suffix is a passage.
>
> My infix is a symbol,
> Mostly known as 32<sub>10</sub>.

Feedback is appreciated.

Looks like it is difficult, so here is a hint:

> There is lots of logic in here, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is probably

> XOR GATE

My Whole is of 2 terms.

> XOR GATE

My Prefix is 3 Letters

> XOR is Three letters

But Term 2 is mostly locked

> GATE is mostly locked

My Prefix is an ex.

> X is also written as ex

My Suffix is a passage.

> Gate is a passage

My infix is a symbol

> Or is a symbol "||"

Comment: Well done. Can you figure the rest?